# two consecutive unions

Tags: sql

Sorry if this question sounds a little silly, but I am not sure what is up with this error.
I am natural joining 3 individual tables with one table, then unioning them together (and eventually pushed into a view yadda yadda). The individual natural joins are good, and they work. Unioning two of them works. Three and it stops.

```
(
  (SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN laptop)
  UNION
  (SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN pc)
)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN printer)
```

Error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN pc) ) UNION (SEL' at line 3`

The error description seems less than useless to me.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT (current progress, some elements missing from "product"):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  (SELECT maker, model, price FROM product NATURAL JOIN laptop)
    UNION
  (SELECT maker, model, price FROM product NATURAL JOIN pc)
    UNION
  (SELECT maker, model, price FROM product NATURAL JOIN printer)
) `Unioned`
```

Comment: I believe it's the parenthesis breaking it.  Have you tried without the parenthesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about this?

```
    SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN laptop
       UNION
    SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN pc
       UNION
    SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN printer
```

be sure to match all fields for each query set.

Comment: This was very close. But for some reason some rows are missing from the main set "product". And indeed the fields were not matching, so I added in the proper projections. I will show the current progress via an edit.

Comment: oh i see, what do you mean by `some elements missing from "product"`? thanks.

Comment: Ah, I got it now. It had nothing to do with the queries. The bd was incomplete and did not contain matching sets for some values. This threw me off in an attempt comparing the data. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using specific column lists instead of wildcard `*` to ensure that the individual sets can be `UNION`-ed.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit looks good because `UNION` (without the `CORRESPONDING` keyword, which isn't supported in mySQL) relies on the unioned tables having the same number of columns of the same type in the same order. Does it work?